# sh script will not execute as root (cron)

Tags: shell, cron

I have the following script added to `cron`. If I add `touch thisisatest.file` to the first line it will create a file named `thisisatest.file`, but not execute the rest of the code. If I manually type `./thescriptname.sh` as root the file will execute as it should. I added `/usr/bin` before `find`, `grep`, and `truncate` as suggested by someone, however the script still will not execute.

```
#!/bin/bash
KEYWORDS=("Word1" "Word2" "Word3" "Word4" "Word5")
IFS=$'\n'
/usr/bin/find /root/ . -size +1c -type f ! -exec /usr/bin/grep -qwF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; -exec /usr/bin/truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

`cronjob -l`:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

*/1 * * * *  /bin/sh /root/miami.sh
root@zzzz:~#
```

Comment: The fact that you put the word PROPERLY in all-caps frankly makes me wonder whether you've really added the script to your crontab properly. Can you show us the relevant crontab entry?

Comment: Please explain how you added your script to cron.

Comment: Also posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21199751/827263) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is `cronjob -e`? What is the output of `crontab -l` *executed as `root`*? Why does a bash script have a `.sh` suffix, and why are you executing it with `/bin/sh` rather than running it directly? You're using some bash-specific features that `/bin/sh` may or may not support, but there's not enough information to know whether that's the problem.

Comment: I haven't the slightest clue how to answer your questions. Any help would be appreciated. Should I change /bin/bash to /bin/sh ?

Comment: You wrote `cronjob -l`. There is no `cronjob` command. Did you mean `crontab -l`? The `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script is correct, but then the correct way to invoke it is just `/root/miami.sh`, not `/bin/sh /root/miami.sh`; you should remove the `/bin/sh` from your cron job. Is the stuff in your question after the incorrect `cronjob` line the output of `crontab -l`? Did you run `crontab -l` as the root user? You refer to both `thescriptname.sh` and `miami.sh`; if those refer to the same thing, please update your question to be more consistent.

Comment: Ah, after reformatting I see that that's a root shell prompt after the `crontab` output.

Answer (score 1):

Check the #!/bin/bash line (the shebang line).
Is this really the first line? Maybe the file starts with some more comment,
the shebang line will be ignored and the script executed with the current shell
(command-line might be bash, crontab will be /bin/sh)
Touch will work, the line with KEYWORDS will fail.

The command after ! should be valid.
When the file is edited on Windows, the line might finish with \r\n.
When the line finishes with a space, than the interpreter will be looking for "bash ".

You said you started the program as ./thescriptname.sh. In this case an invalid shebang will be noticed as well. But maybe you started it with

```
. ./thescriptname.sh
```

When you start the file with a dot, the shebang line is ignored. It would explain why it works using the command-line.

Did crontab supply any output? Maybe your Unix account has mail.
Otherwise change crontab, and redirect stdout and stderr to a tmp file:

```
* * * * *  /bin/sh /root/miami.sh > /tmp/miami.out 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an advice and opinion;
Try your script move to

- /usr/local/sbin  or
- /usr/local/bin  or
- /usr/sbin  or
- /usr/bin or
- /sbin  or
- /bin  or

that are known by cron(shown in PATH variable)

and

just add to crontab as script name.